# CentOS/Plesk 10 migration failure

Tags: centos

I have 2 dedicated servers both running CentOS 5.3 and Plesk 10.0.0.

I'm trying to migrate stuff from one to the other but it's not happening, just after I fill out "Migration settings" and press "Next" I get "Host xx.xx.xx.xx is not accessible"

What I've done so far that didn't have any effect whatsoever:

stopped the firewall on the source server
enabled "PermitRootLogin yes" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restarted the service

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I was able to initiate the migration from the new server (which is blank) to an old one (I need vice versa), so there's definitely something relating to settings.

I pulled out a log file, and this is where it fails:

```
23117: 2011-08-22 16:34:22,949 INFO Executing <subprocess[23118] '/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/launchpad --send-scout --host=XX.XXX.XXX.XXX --login=root --session-path=/usr/local/psa/PMM/msessions/2011082216342281'>
23117: 2011-08-22 16:34:32,983 INFO Subprocess raised ExecuteException: Subprocess <subprocess[23118] '/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/launchpad --send-scout --host=XX.XXX.XXX.XXX --login=root --session-path=/usr/local/psa/PMM/msessions/2011082216342281'> was finished with exit code 10
== STDOUT ====================

== STDERR ====================
Cannot send scout to the remote host
23117: 2011-08-22 16:34:32,983 ERROR Subprocess <subprocess[23118] '/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/launchpad --send-scout --host=XX.XXX.XXX.XXX --login=root --session-path=/usr/local/psa/PMM/msessions/2011082216342281'> was finished with exit code 10
== STDOUT ====================

== STDERR ====================
Cannot send scout to the remote host
23117: 2011-08-22 16:34:32,983 INFO Outgoing packet:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<errcode>130</errcode>
<errmsg>Host XX.XXX.XXX.XXX is not accessible</errmsg>
</response>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved, it's not Plesk related it's a very generic one. The new server was not able to SSH the old server because hosts.allow didn't have "all" enabled...